# How to create like .xcappdata without using xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, backup

It is possible to create .xcappdata like file without using xCode.

Actually Our user is facing problem with there iPod, So they want to restore the iPod and remove all the application but the application contain some important data. All data is stored in Document folder.
Because they don't have xcode so they are unable to create .xappdata.

So please help if anyone have alternative way of downloading document folder without using organizer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a host of desktop applications which allow you to browse usb-connected iOS devices.

- iExplorer: http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/
- i-FunBox: http://www.i-funbox.com/
- iTools: http://www.itools.cn/en_index.htm
- DiskAid: http://www.digidna.net/diskaid

I use IExplorer. There is a free demo version and an option to buy.